# When Click and item on Recyclerview , shows a Dialog and get user input and update that value in recycler item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

**This is the onBinderViewHolder on the Adapter I used to connect data to Recyclerview**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter_PO_Brands.BrandViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DrugData DD = mDrugData.get(position);
    holder.txtBrand.setText(DD.getBrand());
    holder.txtGeneric.setText(DD.getGeneric());
 
    holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ShowAddPOQty(holder.txtQty,DD);
    });
}
```

**This is the ShowAddPOQty Method use to generate the dialog**

```
 public void ShowAddPOQty (TextView Qty ,DrugData dd) {
    dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_po_qty);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    
    TextView txtQty=dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
    TextView Increase=dialog.findViewById(R.id.increase);
    TextView Decrease=dialog.findViewById(R.id.decrease);

    MaterialButton btAdd=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);
    MaterialButton btCancel=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Cancel);

    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Qty.setText("Qty : "+txtQty.getText().toString());
            dialog.cancel();
        
    });


    dialog.show();
}
```

The Thing I wanted to do is , When I click an item on Recyclerview , I want to show a dialog . The user set a quantity and click on Add button on dialog. Then I need to update that value on the recyclerview item that user clicked. The above code update the value in various items in the recyclerview. Not only in the item the user clicked.

**Deperately needed your help thanks.**

Comment: you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged();` after adding data

Comment: @RDX , Thank you so much, It works

Comment: @SupunAyeshmantha It is not efficient to use `notifyDataSetChanged();` for what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Praveen huh, does not matter how much data you have because recyclerview process that data only that can be show in the view

Comment: @Praveen please also share your efficient solution, because a solution never be permanent

Comment: @RDX For making small changes in the recyclerview it's inefficient to call `notifyDataSetChanged();`. The optimal approach is to call `notifyItemChanged(itemPosition);` which will draw the only item with any change, while it's also not the most optimized solution. The most efficient approach is to use `notifyItemChanged` with payloads, for more info on payload read this article - https://medium.com/livefront/recyclerview-trick-selectively-bind-viewholders-with-payloads-4b28e3d2cce8

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this method in adapter then do:

take which object of list you want to change in method and after changing that object instance notify the recycler adapter

```
public void ShowAddPOQty (TextView Qty ,DrugData dd) {
    dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_po_qty);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    
    TextView txtQty=dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
    TextView Increase=dialog.findViewById(R.id.increase);
    TextView Decrease=dialog.findViewById(R.id.decrease);

    MaterialButton btAdd=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);
    MaterialButton btCancel=dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Cancel);

    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Qty.setText("Qty : "+txtQty.getText().toString());
            
            // here change your object values
            dd.setValue(value); 
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.cancel();
        
    });


    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: You can also pass index, and then only notifyItemChange(index) from before dialog dismiss, I think it will more optimized way if list are not change in background. If its helpful then please accept and upvote

Comment: @blackapps Sorry for that will remember for next time

Comment: @Supun Ayeshmantha Please accept this answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @DeePanShu It worked , I got the concept . Thanks. Sorry I dont have reputation to upvote